# Use OAuth for the Goodreads API

Tags: oauth, krl

I'm thinking about creating an app that uses the [Goodreads API](http://www.goodreads.com/api). Part of that is read-only and doesn't require any authentication. But in order to access the write portions of the API, I have to authenticate the user via OAuth.

The Twitter API (which is built in to the language) also uses OAuth, and using it is a simple matter of providing the developer keys and calling `twitter:authorize()`.

Is there a similar way to use OAuth from other APIs with Kynetx?

Comment: Not sure. I'll have to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it and if there is, it's no yet documented. I hear that it is really close though, and I will try to let you know asap.